# Lua: make module system

Tags: module, include, lua

I want to create a program which will have several modules in different folders. Main program will determine which module need to load and will load it. Beside it will load some core functions too.

I created prototype of this logic and it works good.
But since I'm new in [Lua](http://www.lua.org/), I'm not sure what went right way to implement this.

For now I have next structure of files:

[image]

**aoc** (main program):

```
aoc = {}
aoc_base_path = debug.getinfo(1).source:match("@(.*)/.*$") -- base path to my program
if not aoc_base_path then
  aoc_base_path = ''
else
  aoc_base_path = aoc_base_path..'/'
end

local aoc_base_arg={...}
dofile(aoc_base_path.."core/core")

local module = assert(loadfile(aoc_base_path.."modules/"..aoc_base_arg[1].."/module"))
local arg = table.copy(aoc_base_arg) -- this is my custom function (I'm not provide you with listing, it just copy one table to another one
table.remove(arg,1)
module(arg,aoc) -- pass to module all arguments except first one
```

**core/core** (core functions loader):

```
dofile (aoc_base_path..'core/move')
```

**core/move**:

```
local function move(direction, refuel, dig, attack)
  -- some logic in local function (to not be overwriten in module)
end

function aoc.move()
  -- global function (it logic can be changed by module in case it needed)
  return move()
end
```

**modules/mine/module** (module):

```
local arg={...} -- I passed 2 arguments in aoc main program
arg = arg[1]
local aoc = arg[2]
aoc.move()
```

For now

> **lua>** aoc mine

or

> **lua>** path/to/aoc mine

work OK. But can anyone point me if I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** changed logic with getting `aoc_base_path`

Comment: You might also want to fiddle with package_path an require a bit. Maybe that way would work better.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz If you mean line with `debug.getinfo(1).source:match("@(.*)/.*$")` it is only an example. Actualy I get this path in some diferent way (my program is a mod for some game wich provide me `shell.getRunningProgram()` function).

Comment: Is it a typo: `match("@(.*)/.*$")`?  Probably, `match'^(.*)/'` was mentioned?  It also could be written as `match'(.*)/'`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff nope: `echo 'print(debug.getinfo(1).source)' > test; lua test` gives `@test`

Comment: @ArthurHalma - Thanks for information.  Never used this feature before.

Comment: Did you try simply using `require`?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov but in this case lua will searches for the file in a PATH directories. And for example if there will be third-party library with the same name as my module it will be loaded instead of my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify **aoc** a bit:

```
aoc = {}
aoc_base_path = debug.getinfo(1).source:match("@(.*/)") or ''

dofile(aoc_base_path.."core/core")

local module = assert(loadfile(aoc_base_path.."modules/".. ... .."/module"))
module({select(2,...)},aoc)
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain me what three dots here `"modules/".. ... .."/module"` mean (I playing with Lua less than 24 hours)? I think   it will be an error when **aoc** get more than 1 argument.

Comment: @ArthurHalma - If a vararg expression is used inside another expression, then it is adjusted to one element.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Lua's library built-in module functionality with [`require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require). With proper set-up of [`package.loaders`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.loaders) you can configure this standard system to load modules from wherever you want and in any manner you want. Specific directories, directly from HTTP, delivered by pigeons according to RFC 1149 - it can do it all.

Comment: What benefits of this method?

Comment: It is standard, built-in and extensible at that. What more do you need?

Comment: Looks like it is what I need ;). What about structure of my files, may I leave it like it is now?

Comment: @ArthurHalma, absolutely. By default dots in module names translate to sub-directories in file system.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your directory structure more or less the same but make use of the lua package system you could use an approach like this:

In your base path have a file `aoc.lua`:

```
local aoc = {}

local module = ...
local dir = module:gsub("%.","%/"):sub(1,-4)

package.path = dir.."?.lua;"..package.path
package.path = dir.."?/init.lua;"..package.path
package.path = dir.."modules/?.lua;"..package.path

return aoc
```

In /core have a file `init.lua` that `require`s the core packages that you want to include

```
require"core.move"
```

Then your core packages will look something like:

```
local function move(direction, refuel, dig, attack)
  -- some logic in local function (to not be overwriten in module)
end

require"aoc".move = move
```

In /modules you can then make things a bit simpler by having a lua file for each module so /modules/mine.lua would look like:

```
local aoc = require"aoc"

aoc.move()
```

Then at the lua prompt you'd write:

lua> require"path.to.aoc"

lua> require"core" --load up the core modules

lua> require"mine" -- load mine

### Edit

If you want to maintain identically the same style, change aoc.lua to be just `return {}` and add a file aoc as follows:

```
local dir = debug.getinfo(1).source:match("@(.*)/.*$") -- base path to my program
if not dir then dir = ''
else dir = dir..'/'
end

package.path = dir.."?.lua;"..package.path
package.path = dir.."?/init.lua;"..package.path
package.path = dir.."modules/?.lua;"..package.path

require"core"
for _,mod in ipairs{...} do
    require(mod)
end
```

I would suggest that the advantage of this approach is that all of the mangling is in one file, aoc in this case, and the rest of the file structure is using fairly standard lua package conventions.

Comment: There will be no chance to execute my program as `path/to/aoc mine` anymore?

Comment: Looks like I have no access to `package`. Since I doing an plugin for one game I have an limited lua. So your code `package.path = dir.."?.lua;"..package.path` return `attemp to index ? (a nil value)` error.